# how to override permission manager in android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, autostart

i m creating app that has permission to autostart with boot. and **it is working fine on those mobile that does not contains Permission manager.**

i want to start my app like Whats App and Wechat and other app does. But permission manager stop my app to auto start - MI Redme Note 4g mobile and Samsung mobile. Basically, **i want to override the permission manager setting so that my app will start**

currently i m using these code

```
 <receiver
     android:name=".BootComplete"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false" >
       <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

  <service android:name=".AutoStartUp" >
  </service>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Please Advice  me to get my app auto start  like **Whats App, Wechat, Youtube** and  Other app does

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does here is that: When the device is booted it will tell the broadcast receiver, now the broadcast receiver needs to start the Service or App or whatever you want to start:

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent0) {



        if(! isMyServiceRunning(MyFirstService.class, context)){//test

        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyFirstService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
        }




    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context context) {


        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)context. getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This code also checks if the Service is already running (for some reason) and you can remove that part if you want.

Comment: Good idea @Mr. M , i m going to implement it

Comment: I wish someone was there when I needed this a few years ago. If it works check this answer as correct for future reference.